# How i can use pinch zoom in /out using jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using Phonegap and i want to use zoom in / out option on pinch using jquery mobile.
I have tried jgesture and hammer plugins for zooming it. Where i am wrong in this code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" />
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
                 $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
      $.mobile.metaViewportContent = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2";
});
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use hammer.js pinch, pinchin, pinchout

Here's the event documentation for their API on github:

https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started

ALSO you've essentially made it not user scalable...:

```
initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1,
```

This line:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,
minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi"/>
```

And then you use jquery to set it again:

```
$.mobile.metaViewportContent = "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2";
```

No good, read up on it here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta

Comment: I have also tried hammer.js , but its not working for me. May be i am not able to use it. Would you please send any documentation of using hammer.js in case of pinch

Comment: Added extra info, you have max and min scale set to the same number. Cheers!

Comment: I have set maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1 and user-scalable=no ... still its not working in my case

Comment: You need to make them not equal and allow user scaling was my point

Comment: Now i changed maximum-scale=2, minimum-scale=1 and user-scalable=yes ... still not working

Comment: See my edit for more things you need to address. Search on MDN for help